# How to include blank value in Former::select

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using the [Former](https://github.com/Anahkiasen/former) package for Laravel 4, along with [TwigBridge](https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge).  I have a select field that I'm populating with a model:

```
{{ former_select('parent_id').fromQuery(sections, 'title', 'id') }}
```

However, I'd also like to add a blank value as the default option.  I've looked through the docs but could not see anything that mentioned this.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Former version 2.6.0 I had to use the 'placeholder' method

```
{{ Former::select('author_id')->placeholder('Please select')->label('author')->fromQuery(Author::get(), 'username', 'id') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

It was actually quite simple.  Just use the addOption method and leave the parameters blank

```
{{ former_select('parent_id').addOption().fromQuery(sections) }}
```

Comment: Or e.g.
{!! Former::select('_dbColumn_', '_formLabel_')->addOption('None', 0)->fromQuery(App\_Model_::where('_dbColumn_', '_match_')->orderBy('_orderColumn_', 'ASC')->get(), '_optionText_', '_optionValue_')->placeholder('Select') !!}